# Unexpected behavior with ParSet's zipWithIndex

Tags: scala

I found some interesting behavior of Scala 2.9.2 ParSet zipWithIndex, and I was wondering if this is a bug or a feature. I apologize if the answer is obvious as I am a Scala beginner.

Here is a session demonstrating the issue.

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_21).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val x = Array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
x: Array[Int] = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)

// expected behavior

scala> x.toSet
res6: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

scala> x.toSet.zipWithIndex
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Set[(Int, Int)] = Set((1,1), (3,5), (4,7), (5,0), (6,2), (2,3), (8,6), (7,4))

// so far so good. let's try parallel implementation

scala> x.par.toSet
res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSet[Int] = ParSet(5, 1, 6, 2, 7, 3, 8, 4)

// 
// 
// UNEXPECTED BEHAVIOR HERE
// 
scala> x.par.toSet.zipWithIndex
res1: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSet[(Int, Int)] = ParSet((5,7), (6,5), (2,4), (1,6), (3,2), (4,0), (7,3), (8,1))

// just for good measure, this isn't an issue with Array or ParArray:
scala> x.zipWithIndex
res3: Array[(Int, Int)] = Array((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,4), (6,5), (7,6), (8,7))

scala> x.par.zipWithIndex
res7: scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray[(Int, Int)] = ParArray((1,0), (2,1), (3,2), (4,3), (5,4), (6,5), (7,6), (8,7))
```

Is this expected behavior? Why is the behavior of ParSet not equivalent to Set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The order of elements is unexpected by definition of sets — implementation specific order. When you do `zipWithIndex` you actually reveal different order in different implementations.

   If you take other `Set` implementations, you will get the other order and accordingly the other set of pairs `(orderPos, element)`.
2. The other source of unexpected behavior is nonassociativeness of `zipWithIndex`:
   http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/overview.html#nonassociative_operations

   I think that if you run `x.par.toSet.zipWithIndex` many times you can get different results from time to time (probably for longer collections).

   **Updated**

   I've run it a couple of times:

   ```
   scala>  x.par.toSet.zipWithIndex
   res0: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSet[(Int, Int)] = 
    ParSet((4,0), (8,1), (1,6), (6,5), (7,3), (5,7), (3,2), (2,4))

   scala>  x.par.toSet.zipWithIndex
   res1: scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParSet[(Int, Int)] = 
    ParSet((4,0), (8,1), (6,5), (2,4), (3,3), (1,7), (7,2), (5,6))
   ```

   The results are different.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's an associativity problem. Associativity is a property (`a * (b * c) = (a * b) * c`) of a binary operation (`*`), and `zipWithIndex` isn't one. This problem stems entirely from your #1 point. As alluded to in your link, for reductions over sets, you need to ensure that your operation is commutative so that it isn't influenced by the arbitrary order of the elements. Note that this is distinct from the reduction order, which is what associativity affects.

Comment: I think that the implementation of `zipWithIndex` can be `foldLeft` with some running state (that includes the intermediate result and the current index) + a binary operation that increments the current index. And that operation seems to be nonassociative.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if zipWithIndex was guaranteed to be consistent with the order of iteration, but as you point out order of iteration is not guaranteed with sets (even if one is used to them being guaranteed ;), and also the order of iteration is not even guaranteed with parallel collections.